# How to convert a string to Object in JavaScript with data coming by div data- atribute?

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML page where I call some JavaScript's codes. There is a div where I pass in the atribute "data-" some data that will be collect by a javascript function.

The problem is that, when I collect the data, that is a string in object format ("{'name':'William', 'lastName':'Zimmermann'}") and I try to parse it to a JSON object, I can't use the vars of this object, it returns "undefined"...

Follow the example about what I'm trying to do (will be better to explain):

**index.html**

```
<script src="dashboard/assets/mycharts.js">
...
<div id="chartProducao" data-production="{{ production }}"></div>
# production = {'actual_production': '2', 'month_goal': '2', 'goal': '111,11111857143'}
...
```

**dashboard/assets/mycharts.js**

```
var production_data = document.getElementById('chartProducao').dataset.production;
console.log(production_data); //{'actual_production': '2', 'month_goal': '2', 'goal': '111,11111857143'}
var production_obj = JSON.parse(production_data);
console.log(production_obj.goal); //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at window.onload (graficos.js:263)
```

What I'm doing wrong? Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]  - right now your code and other stuff is just a jumble of letters. It seems your JSON is not valid?

Comment: It says right there in the error message what the problem is... "Unexpected token ' in JSON". JSON doesn't allow single quotes.

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: its already an Object you dont have to parse it again!

Comment: @anchreg No, it is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting an answer to avoid more discussion

1. Your string does not parse because it is invalid JSON - single quotes not allowed
2. Yes you do have to parse the **string** returned from the dataset

This works as expected (swapping quotes)

```js
var production_data = document.getElementById('chartProducao').dataset.production;
console.log(typeof production_data,production_data); 
var production_obj = JSON.parse(production_data);
console.log(production_obj.goal);
```

```html
<div id="chartProducao" data-production='{"actual_production": "2", "month_goal": "2", "goal": "111,11111857143"}'></div>
```

So does this (replacing quotes):

```js
var production_data = document.getElementById('chartProducao').dataset.production;
console.log(typeof production_data,production_data); 
var production_obj = JSON.parse(production_data.replace(/'/g,'"'));
console.log(production_obj.goal);
```

```html
<div id="chartProducao" data-production=" {'actual_production': '2', 'month_goal': '2', 'goal': '111,11111857143'}"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/stringify) function.

```
JSON.Stringify(jsonObj);
```